# Is it possible that disappearing a scope in gin-gonic binded json?

Tags: json, go, go-gin

I'm writing an api server with gin-gonic.

And I got in trouble that associated with marshaling json.

For example, I have a Structure likes below.

```golang
type Foo struct {
    Value     float32 `json:"value"`
    Injection interface{}
}
```

And I wrote down some fields in run time and send response.

```golang
r.GET("/ping", func(c *gin.Context) {

    var foo = &Foo{
        Value: 19.8,
        Injection: map[string]interface{}{
            "unit": "C",
            "constraints": map[string]interface{}{
                "min": 18,
                "max": 30,
            },
        },
    }

    c.JSON(200, foo)
})
```

As a result, I can see this json response.

```
{
    "value": 19.8,
    "Injection": {
        "constraints": {
            "max": 30,
            "min": 18
        },
        "unit": "C"
    }
}
```

But if I want to have likes below, what can I do?

```
{
    "value": 19.8,
    "constraints": {
        "max": 30,
        "min": 18
    },
    "unit": "C"
}
```

I tried to assign all field in run time, It's work properly in first time, but after add many many fields I met hell gate.

So I can say It's similar problem `<Fragment>` tag in React.

ps. sorry I can't sure the title is correspond with my mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the map directly instead of `Foo`.

```
r.GET("/ping", func(c *gin.Context) {
    var data = map[string]interface{}{
        "value": 19.8,
        "unit":  "C",
        "constraints": map[string]interface{}{
            "min": 18,
            "max": 30,
        },
    }

    c.JSON(200, data)
})
```

If you need something more generic you could have `Foo` implement the `json.Marshaler` interface and have the implementation marshal the two values separately and then just "merge" the results manually.

```
type Foo struct {
    Value     float32     `json:"value"`
    Injection interface{} `json:"-"`
}

func (f *Foo) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    type tmp Foo
    out1, err := json.Marshal((*tmp)(f))
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    out2, err := json.Marshal(f.Injection)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    out1[len(out1)-1] = ','           // replace the '}' at the end with ','
    out2 = out2[1:]                   // drop the leading '{'
    return append(out1, out2...), nil // merge
}
```

Note the above assumes that `Injection` holds a value that will be marshaled into a json *object*, if the value is a scalar, or a slice type, you'll need to handle those cases differently.

https://play.golang.com/p/kYIu6HnqVIp